# How can I expose the internal api of a VUE3 application through Cypress?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, vuejs3

I am new to Cypress and I have stumbled upon an issue I cannot resolve. I tried to expose the internal api of the app I am testing through Cypress(application actions) by setting the following:

const app = createApp(App);

window.ui = app;

But when I access it in Cypress trough cy.window().then(({ win }) => { win.ui... }); it is not exposing the functions I would like to access, but another window object.

I have seen that all examples from the internet I could find are for vue2 applications and we are using vue3. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the methods I was trying to expose, but they are not in the ui object, but at the following path:

win.ui._context.app._component.__c.components.SidebarRight.__c.methods.toggleSidebarLayout();